# VGA Monitor won't work after NVIDIA driver update on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, driver

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04, and the first thing that came up was the driver manager, which told me to install the drivers for my nvidia graphics card (I don't remember what it is).

I have a laptop and my screen is broken, so I must use an external monitor to see what is on my screen. After the install and restart, the external monitor is no longer detected. How can this be fixed? I know the display still works because i can see the bottom corner of my laptop screen.

When I revert back to before I installed the driver the external monitor will display again.

Comment: Better to ask at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Please stop downvoting this, it is closed and I am unable to delete.

Comment: You should probably go back to the open source driver (which is fine for kicad etc) *BUT* you can get a real problem with this. The Nvidia can black-list the old driver and when uninstalled leaves the black-list file in place leaving you with a low res screen. The way to fix it is to go to /etc/modprobe.d and look for a file named something like nvidia_graphics_drivers....conf. Either delete this or rename it to something without .conf at the end. reboot. It should now work properly.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to use an external monitor:

1) "Ctl-Alt-F1" will take you to text mode, where you should be able to fix the driver issue

2) You should be able to reboot ("sudo reboot -i" from a command prompt) and go into "VESA mode" from the boot menu

3) This link has several good suggestions, including this:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/125537/nvidia-graphics-resolution-problems-with-new-12-04-lts-installation

> There are a lot of issues with the 295.40 driver. You can revert to
>   the old nvidia driver 295.33 by following this guide:
>
> http://www.noobslab.com/2011/09/nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html
>
> I have to manually load the nvidia_current kernel module by adding
>   nvidia_current to /etc/modules -- works after reboot, executing
>   "modprobe nvidia_current" and "/etc/init.d/lightdm restart" works
>   immediately